# Consumindo Funções do C#(dll) em um projeto C/C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Estou precisando chamar/reutilizar algumas funções que tenho em uma DLL, desenvolvida em C#, dentro de um projeto feito em C.

Já procurei algumas coisas e o que consegui fazer funcionar legal foi este projeto:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736

Este artigo, passo a passo, descreve como chamar uma DLL em C++ nativo. Funciona legal.

Meu problema é que este processo utiliza registro de Windows e a geração do arquivo .tlb. Isso está me gerando muito problema, pois quando eu faço qualquer alteração na minha DLL, o programa em C para de funcionar, mesmo recompilando tudo.

Então procurando encontrei este outro método:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Consuming-C-Library-in-937458e5

Ele explica como consumir uma biblioteca C# em C/C++ sem a utilização de exportação e importação .tlb (o que me geraria menor dor de cabeça).

Eu acredito que este segundo método é mais eficiente e possui uma interface muito melhor.

O problema é que este segundo método é muito mais complicado e eu não tenho um domínio muito grande em C/C++. Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por este problema e poderia me dar uma ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Eu já tive que fazer isso, e utilizei uma abordagem um pouco diferente (testei esse procedimento no Visual Studio 2012 e 2013).

Para o teste, criei uma DLL em C#, chamada de **BibliotecaCSharp.dll**, com a seguinte classe e namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BibliotecaCSharp
{
    public class Teste
    {
        public int Soma(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Agora, do lado do C++, em outro projeto, para executar um código de uma biblioteca em .Net (seja C#, VB etc), o projeto C++ deve estar configurado para suportar a CLR, como mostrado na figura:

[image: Configuração do projeto]

Uma vez configurado o projeto, é necessário importar as bibliotecas necessárias, o que é feito dentro do arquivo `stdafx.h` do seu projeto em C++, bastando acrescentar essas linhas a ele:

```
//Includes e bibliotecas específicas do runtime para .Net
#include <mscoree.h>
#include <vcclr.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib")
```

A partir de agora, é possível instanciar classes escritas em C#, ou VB.Net diretamente de dentro do código C++.

Esse projeto de exemplo em C++ é uma aplicação console simples, com apenas um arquivo cpp, mas serve para demonstrar a técnica:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

//Em todos os arquivos que forem acessar a classe, deve-se
//importar as bibliotecas e namespaces
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "<CAMINHO DA DLL EM C#>\BibliotecaCSharp.dll"

using namespace System;
using namespace BibliotecaCSharp;

int SomaCSharp(int a, int b)
{
    //Cria uma instância da classe desejada
    Teste^ t = gcnew Teste();

    return t->Soma(a, b);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int s = SomaCSharp(1, 2);

    _tprintf(TEXT("Soma em C#: %d\n"), s);

    return 0;
}
```

Contudo, do jeito que está, o código em C++ dará erro durante a execução, pois o `#using "<CAMINHO DA DLL EM C#>\BibliotecaCSharp.dll"` serve apenas para o compilador localizar a biblioteca, e **não** para o programa localizar a biblioteca quando estiver executando.

Para esse fim, eu sempre copio a dll em C# para a mesma pasta do executável em C++, como mostra a figura abaixo:

[image: Arquivos na pasta]

Seria possível copiar para outra pasta, desde que ela esteja no **PATH** do sistema, mas acho a solução de utilizar a mesma pasta mais simples.

Só como curiosidade, essa cópia pode ser automatizada através do **Post-build event command line**, como mostra a figura:

[image: Post-build event command line]

Comment: É **necessário** criar a classe com `gcnew` nesse caso? Ou funcionaria sem problemas com a classe criada na stack?

Comment: Sim, deve-se utilizar o `gcnew`, sempre que a classe instanciada for **managed**. Dessa forma o objeto que vai para o Managed heap, onde o garbage collector pode agir. Se utilizasse só `new`, o objeto iria para o heap normal do sistema, e o garbage collector não teria como monitora-lo. Para evitar isso, o compilador já nem permite a compilação de um código com a construção `new Classe()`, onde `Classe` é uma classe managed.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que alterações em sua DLL escrita em C# tenham efeito sobre seu programa C++, impedindo este de funcionar corretamente, tente fixar o identificador global de seu módulo usando as instruções contidas neste [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vcwlkcominteroptutorialcreatinganunmanagedcomclasswrapper).

Veja:

```
// 
// declare FilgraphManager as a COM coclass 
// 
[ComImport, Guid("E436EBB3-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770")] 
class FilgraphManager
{ 
}
```

Os nomes de interfaces públicas também não devem ser alteados.